# Android Intent-filter mimetype and host/scheme

Tags: android, host, intentfilter

I've seen in some apps that when you click on a link it asks you if you want to open it in an app. I've seen in many posts that you can do

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="www.ex-ample.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

I haven't tried it, but every post seems to say it works. What I tried was:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.crag" />
  <data android:host="www.ex-ample.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

and it doesn't seem to work, I clicked on a link in a text that went to www.ex-ample.com/test/123 and it just opened in a browser.

I'm really wondering two things:

1. can you use a mineType and a host/scheme attribute together
2. can you see anything else wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can you use a mineType and a host/scheme attribute together

Yes, at least according to [the docs on `<data>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html).

> can you see anything else wrong with this?

If http://www.ex-ample.com/test/123 does not return a document of MIME type `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.crag` on an HTTP HEAD request, your `<intent-filter>` will not match.

Comment: ok.... I kinda understand. So I'd have to set the mimetype of my webpage to be vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.crag and not text/html? Do you have an example of this? Is this something that people would do?!

Comment: @matt_lethargic: "So I'd have to set the mimetype of my webpage to be vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.crag and not text/html?" -- if you want it to be picked up by your `<intent-filter>`, yes. "Do you have an example of this?" -- that would be a question for whoever maintains your Web server or Web app that is serving the content. "Is this something that people would do?!" -- I suspect that filtering on a path prefix is more common.

Comment: this set of code in manifest 
   
  <data android:host="www.ex-ample.com" android:scheme="http" />
  would open the app in my emulators when the browser opens www.ex-ample.com but not on my samsung s3 and htc one x. does the browsers override that functionality and is there something we can do.

Comment: @visista: On the HTCs, there is little that you can do, as HTC made some changes in response to an Apple lawsuit. See http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/23/linkify-problem-patent-behavior.html and http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/24/linkify-problem-detection-mitigation.html I was not aware that Samsung had done similar things, and I will need to do more research on that point.

Comment: @visista: FWIW, this project works on a Samsung Galaxy S3: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler Run the sample, click the button to bring up the test page in a browser, and in the browser click on the "Link to www.this-so-does-not-exist.com" link. That will bring up a chooser, offering my app as an option, and tapping on my app will bring it up.

Comment: @CommonsWare : need your help for a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583377/how-many-scheme-host-tags-can-come-under-intent-filter-in-android-manifest                                                              Kindly help.

Comment: @CommonsWare hey sorry was a late. yes, it worked on S3. hoping to see the htc guys come up with a solution.