# How many scheme & host tags can come under intent-filter in android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, host, intentfilter

Need more info regarding intent-filter tag specified in manifest. I am aware that we can specify data in two forms:

```
<intent-filter>
     <data android:host="com.myHost" android:scheme="content"/>
</intent-filter>
```

AND :

```
<intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="content"/>
     <data android:host="com.myHost"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But I wish to know can several combinations exist, like

```
<intent-filter>
         <data android:host="com.myHost" android:scheme="content"/>
         <data android:scheme="content"/>
         <data android:host="com.myHost1"/>
</intent-filter>
```

OR:

```
<intent-filter>
         <data android:host="com.myHost" android:scheme="content"/>
         <data android:scheme="content"/>
         <data android:host="com.myHost1"/>
         <data android:scheme="content"/>
         <data android:host="com.myHost2"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In the last case, I wish to know firstly if this can exist & how is it decided that which host to be used for which scheme, as the data tags containing scheme & host can occur in any order.

Please help.

Comment: Your data tags with only the host specified are completely ignored by the way. From the Google docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Each of these attributes is optional in a <data> element, but there are linear dependencies:

If a scheme is not specified, the host is ignored.
If a host is not specified, the port is ignored.
If both the scheme and host are not specified, the path is ignored.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I am aware that we can specify data in two forms

Do not use `content` for a scheme, unless you truly mean that you are creating an activity in support of a `ContentProvider`.

> But I wish to know can several combinations exist

If your filter has just one attribute for `<data>`, you definitely can have different values, such as this from the Contacts app:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ShowOrCreateActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also, one component can have several `<intent-filter>` elements, each of which is logically OR'd with the others (any `Intent` matching any filter is a match for the component). So for more complex scenarios, where you have 2+ attributes per `<data>` element, I would be inclined to put those in separate `<intent-filter>` elements.

> how is it decided that which host to be used for which scheme

Any match is considered good. You would examine the `Intent` yourself to learn more about what it contains.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! So ideally if any app needs to specify two content & host combinations, it should put them in two intent-filters !

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases, android docs say: "Note: Intent filters may only contain a single data element for a URI pattern. Create separate intent filters to capture additional URI patterns."

Answer (score 16):

Complementing @CommonsWare answer, it appears that you cannot use two `<data>` tags if you are not so specific.

A) In one of my apps I can have:

```
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme1"/>
```

B) And

```
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme2" android:host="host2"/>
```

C) But the following will ignore the first tag (using `myAppScheme1://whatever` URI won't work):

```
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme1"/>
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme2" android:host="host2"/>
```

D) However if I complement the first scheme it will work for both URIS:

```
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme1" android:host="host1"/>
<data android:scheme="myAppScheme2" android:host="host2"/>
```

Probably if you really need the case C), you'll better create two intent-filters