# Prevent multiple intent-filters from matching for oauth redirect

Tags: android, intentfilter

When receiving an OAuth redirect in my app, the Android "Open with" menu shows with 2 choices, both being my application. The desired behavior would be to simply proceed into the app without showing the "Open with" menu.

This issue started happening after I added a new intent-filter to capture "text/plain" shares from other applications.

Here are my intent-filter that are part of the same activity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="com.app" android:host="app" android:pathPrefix="" />
   <data android:scheme="com.app" android:host="oauth" android:pathPrefix="" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

And the Intent captured using `adb logcat`:

```
{act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=com.app://oauth?code=4pZliH2NrWWoypXnsBqEOjbMramW70&state=6AImyjKHt7ZhYPuk_pJjRQ flg=0x14000000 pkg=com.app cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity (has extras)}
```

Since they are a part of the same activity I assumed that it wouldn't prompt the user to select an option. I also assumed `action.VIEW` would only match the first intent as well.

When attempting to combine intents, the redirect failed to work entirely. And from researching, it doesn't seem like there is a way to prioritize intents.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue. I was using a library (AppAuth-Android) that was injecting its own ...

After removing the library, the issue was resolved. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583377/how-many-scheme-host-tags-can-come-under-intent-filter-in-android-manifest)

You are creating two schemes with same name in same intent-filter.