# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: (at Binary XML file line #23): intent tag may have at most one data scheme

Tags: android, flutter

Error:

> ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to
> install
> /Users/rajvaghasiya/Documents/GitHub/micatalog-3/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1855179046.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #23): intent tag may have at most one data scheme.] Error
> launching application on SM T290.

*I have facing this error in my flutter project.If anyone know solutions Help me.*

Comment: This answer may be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685872/9186913.

Comment: Check with merged manifest as well inside the android module.

Answer (score 0):

There are many potential reasons that might have caused this error. So it's impossible to know the reasons without inspecting your AndroidManifest.xml file.

However, I can provide one possible solution that might have caused this error. If you manually added some package code in `AndroidManifest.xml`, for example `url_launch`.

Do this

```
<queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>

    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

instead of

```
<queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Other reasons that might have also caused the error include your emulator not having enough RAM, or forgetting to add `android:exported="true"`. The solutions for these two issues can be found easily in other posts.